# How to determine winning team from the MLB retrosheet "event" file?

Tags: baseball, statistics, mlb, sabermetrics

As far as I can tell, there isn't a field in the event file (https://www.retrosheet.org/eventfile.htm) that states the winning team. By my understanding it could either be found from the game file (https://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/glfields.txt), or calculated from runs scored, or by matching the winning pitcher (which IS in the event file) to his team. Am I missing an easier way to get the winning team from just the event file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no "winning" record in the event file.  That is what the Game file is for.  I don't think there's a better way using the event file than to match the winning pitcher (which is easy enough to do), but the truly best way is to use the correct file for the correct information.

Answer (score -1):

Retrosheet is more specifically for events within a game. Have you checked out Pybaseball module? It contains all of retrosheet data and A TON more. Including the Pybaseball.schedule-and-record(2021,'NYY') you can get game outcomes for entire seasons via the Lahman Database. <--much more versatile than retrosheet for your wanted results IMO. It is the source of alllll my MLB modelling. You can also download the Lahman for free just google seanlahman.com!
https://github.com/jldbc/pybaseball
Goodluck!
-Otot

B.t.w . Also try pybaseball.game_logs() or pybaseball.lahman.teams()will have team level data on a yearly scale. Pybaseball.schedule_and_record(startYYYY, endYYYY*optional*(if nothing entered will end with most recent available info),team abbr."XXX", ind=0or1(0=all data combined to one row, 1=yearlystatsrow are ind. seasons

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. The asker has previously made clear they are seeking determination of the game result from the event file only. Can you clarify how this answer meets that requirement?

Comment: Then no. The asker isnt going to find what they are looking for in that file. Would a better answer have just been:No?

Comment: If that is the actual answer, say so, for example, exactly as the other existing answer does.

Comment: I don't know the Stack Exchange etiquette 100% (perhaps this should be a comment rather than an answer), but as the asker, I appreciate the tip given here. Thank you.